# Sequelize JOSNB Query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I have a table with `JSONB` column in Postgres which is having structure like this

```
{"Name":"f","District Name":"ky","Age":"21","Gender":"M"}

    MyTable.findAll({
       where: {
          'userData.Age':{
            $lt: age,
          }
       }
    })
```

Converted to Query

```
SELECT "id", "uuid", "device_id", "version", "userData", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
FROM "MyTable" AS "MyTable" 
WHERE CAST(("MyTable"."userData"#>>'{Age,$lte}') AS DOUBLE PRECISION) = 40;
```

Next Query is

```
MyTable.findAll({
   where: {
    'userData.Gender':{
        $eq: 'M',
    }
   }
})
```

Converted to Query

```
SELECT "id", "uuid", "device_id", "version", "userData", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
FROM "MyTable" AS "MyTable" 
WHERE ("MyTable"."userData"#>>'{Gender,$eq}') = 'M';
```

Both are returning empty Records, I can think of Age not working as it is text in `JSON`, but Gender should work.

with this raw queries I am getting records.

```
select uuid from "MyTable" where ("userData"->>'Age') :: Integer < 50;

select uuid from "MyTable" where ("userData"->>'Gender') = 'M';
```

Comment: JSONB Sequelize docs are here: https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/querying.html#nested-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**("MyTable"."userData"#>>'{Gender,$eq}') = 'M'**
shows that there is an issue with Sequelize query and reason could be $lte and $eq operators are not working, as operator Aliasing not supported now. Use Op.lte or Op.eq instead.